# No rule to make target modules for nginx pagespeed module

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, makefile

I am building a pagespeed module for nginx as per this doc https://www.nginx.com/blog/optimize-website-google-pagespeed-dynamic-module-nginx-plus/

I am using nginx version: 1.17.9 and PageSpeed version 1.13.35.2.

Everything works except the make modules command.

It give me this error.

> make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.

I also followed the build instructions from here: https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source which resulted into the same.

I am building this on Ubuntu server same as my production server. What could be wrong? And how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that the directory name has changed since this guide has written. I updated script to refer to correct directory and it worked.

This helped
https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-ngx/issues/1512
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ngx-pagespeed-discuss/FgKjl2rF5Rk